# SAS Planet cached tiles for use in Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, tiles

I downloaded some tiles from ArcGIS.Imagery with SAS Planet
The tiles is in folders like

```
ArcGIS.Imagery/z2/0/x1/0/y2.jpg
ArcGIS.Imagery/z13/2/x2624/1/y1750.jpg
```

And I use this TileLayer to display it on Leaflet.

```
  L.TileLayer.customTiles = L.TileLayer.extend({
            getTileUrl: function (t) {
                console.log('coords', t);
                z = t.z,
                    x = t.x,
                    y = t.y,
                    z0 = t.z,
                    x0 = Math.floor(t.x / 1024),
                    x1 = Math.floor(t.x % 1024),
                    y0 = Math.floor(t.y / 1024),
                    y1 = Math.floor(t.y % 1024)

                const d = `ArcGIS.Imagery/z${z0}/${x0}/x${x1}/${y0}/y${y1}.jpg`;
                console.log('d', d);
                return d;
            }
        });
        L.tileLayer.customTiles = function () {
            return new L.TileLayer.customTiles();
        }
        L.tileLayer.customTiles().addTo(map);
```

But it looks like there is wrong coordinates. Here is what I got as a result.

Any ideas how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Which cache type are you using? It looks like rather complex one. Why don't you go for something simpler, like TMS or or GMT?

Comment: @TomazicM I am not sure that it is possible to set the cache type with SAS Planet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the simplest solution for this is to use TMS tiling schema in SAS Planet, since it's natively supported in Leaflet.

In SAS Planet you go to *Settings > Options > Cache*. Then in the *Default cache type* field select "Tile Map service (TMS)" (`CacheType=45`).

The you can declare your TMS layer simply with:

```
var tmsLayer = L.tileLayer('path to cache files/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg', {
    tms: true
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get it to work this way:

Using "GlobalMapper Tiles"

```
L.tileLayer('path to cache files/**z{z}/{y}/{x}**.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked, your code works. [image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Leaflet offline map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8" href="leaflet.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="leaflet.js"></script>
        <script>
            function onLoad() {

                var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([55.74458, 37.60543], 16);

                  L.TileLayer.customTiles = L.TileLayer.extend({
                            getTileUrl: function (t) {
                                console.log('coords', t);
                                    z = t.z,
                                    x = t.x,
                                    y = t.y,
                                    z0 = t.z + 1,
                                    x0 = Math.floor(t.x / 1024),
                                    x1 = Math.floor(t.x % 1024),
                                    y0 = Math.floor(t.y / 1024),
                                    y1 = Math.floor(t.y % 1024)

                                const d = `moscow_osm_20221124/z${z0}/${x0}/x${x}/${y0}/y${y}.png`;
                                console.log('d', d);
                                return d;
                            }
                        });
                        L.tileLayer.customTiles = function () {
                            return new L.TileLayer.customTiles();
                        }
                        L.tileLayer.customTiles().addTo(mymap);
            }
        </script>   
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad();"> 
        <div id="mapid" style="height: 500px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).